# After converting my py file to an exe file using auto-py-to-exe software, the exe file keeps crushing each time I run it, what could be the problem?

Tags: python

I am new to kivy and am working on this simple app where user inputs three numbers then upon pressing pie generator button a pie chart is created

The application is working perfectly as a py file its not rising any issue but after converting it to an exe file using auto-py-to-exe software, it keeps crushing the moment I try to run it.

I have also tried converting it using pyinstaller

I ran cmd code (pyintaller MAT.py -w)

and when I tried to run exe file I got an error
'no module named 'kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg'
of which I have installed kivy-garden using pip install kivy-garden and pip install matplotib

but I keep facing the same problem

below are my py and kv files for your review

your help will be highly appreciated.

MAT.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvasKivyAgg
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from kivy.lang import Builder
import numpy as np

class my_box(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def func_1(self):
        plt.close()
        x = np.array([self.ids.ti_1.text, self.ids.ti_2.text, self.ids.ti_3.text])
        plt.pie(x)

        box_x = self.ids.box_1
        box_x.add_widget(FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf()))

class MATApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return my_box()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    matapp=MATApp()
    MATApp().run()
```

This is my kv file

mat.kv

```
<my_box>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing: 5

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            spacing: 5

            Label:
                text: 'Input a number in each input box'
            TextInput:
                id: ti_1
                hint_text: '#1'
            TextInput:
                id: ti_2
                hint_text: '#2'
            TextInput:
                id: ti_3
                hint_text: '#3'
            Button:
                text: 'Pie Genrator'
                on_press:
                    root.func_1()

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            
            BoxLayout:
                id: box_1
```

Comment: Python wasn't create to build .exe programs and tools like `auto-to-exe` may have problem to find all needed Python modules (and/or C/C++ libraries). I don't know `auto-to-exe` but it probably use `pyinstaller` and in this tool you may use special file `.spec` to manually add some modules or files  [Using Spec Files](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/spec-files.html)

Comment: Thank for your response, I will try pyinstaller then add the missing modules in the spec file